# trying to add an agent (not allowing duplicate last names). Initial total sales should be zero

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am receiving the following error when trying to compile and execute. I am having issues how to figure this out.
14/7      PL/SQL: Statement ignored
14/10     PLS-00204: function or pseudo-column 'EXISTS' may be used inside a SQL statement only
Errors: check compiler log

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE AddAgent(
    p_Agent_Fname IN Agent.Agent_Fname%TYPE,
    p_Agent_Lname IN Agent.Agent_Lname%TYPE,
    p_Agent_Address IN Agent.Agent_Address%TYPE,
    p_Agent_Tsales IN Agent.Agent_Tsales%TYPE,
    p_Agent_Salary IN Agent.Agent_Salary%TYPE)

IS
        p_ErrorCode number;     --USED FOR ERROR CHECKING
        p_ErrorMsg  Varchar2(200);
        p_CurrentUser Varchar2(100);
BEGIN

  IF EXISTS 
  (SELECT * FROM Agent WHERE Agent_Lname = p_Agent_Lname) THEN

      dbms_output.put_line('Failure');    
  ELSE
     INSERT INTO Agent (Agent_Fname, Agent_Lname, Agent_Address, Agent_Tsales, Agent_Salary) 
     SELECT p_Agent_Fname, p_Agent_Lname, p_Agent_Address, 0, p_Agent_Salary
     from Dual;
     COMMIT;

     dbms_output.put_line('Success');
    END IF;
END;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you were told, you can't use `EXISTS` out of the `SELECT` statement. Therefore, you'll have to check for existence in the `AGENT` table elsewhere.

Here's one option you might consider. Note that I've also rewritten the `INSERT INTO` statement - there's no need to `SELECT FROM DUAL`, you already have all those values.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE AddAgent(
    p_Agent_Fname   IN Agent.Agent_Fname%TYPE,
    p_Agent_Lname   IN Agent.Agent_Lname%TYPE,
    p_Agent_Address IN Agent.Agent_Address%TYPE,
    p_Agent_Tsales  IN Agent.Agent_Tsales%TYPE,
    p_Agent_Salary  IN Agent.Agent_Salary%TYPE)
IS
    p_ErrorCode   number;     --USED FOR ERROR CHECKING
    p_ErrorMsg    Varchar2(200);
    p_CurrentUser Varchar2(100);

    l_cnt         number;    --> newly added
BEGIN
  -- check whether something exists in a table
  select count(*)
    into l_cnt
    from dual
    where exists (select null 
                  from agent
                  where agent_lname = p_agent_lname
                 );

  IF l_cnt > 0 then
     dbms_output.put_line('Failure');    
  ELSE
     INSERT INTO Agent 
       (Agent_Fname, Agent_Lname, Agent_Address, Agent_Tsales, Agent_Salary) 
     VALUES
       (p_Agent_Fname, p_Agent_Lname, p_Agent_Address, 0, p_Agent_Salary);

     COMMIT;
     dbms_output.put_line('Success');  
  END IF;
END;
/
```